# setting size of richtextbox in inch independent of size and resolution of monitor

Tags: wpf

I am using a richtextbox in a wpf application. I want to set width of rtb to 8.5" and height of rtb to 11.0". It should be independent of resolution, size of the monitor. Kindly help me in this context.

Answer (score 0):

There is no uniform way to do this for all monitors.  You [can set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx) width in inches but it is implied that monitor has 96 DPI.  There is [an article](http://www.odewit.net/ArticleContent.aspx?id=WpfDpiScaling&lang=en) that explains it in detail.